# Order / sort links in number order using jquery

Tags: jquery, numbers, hyperlink, title

I have a list of links with number ids in the titles, using jQuery how can I order them in id order Highest  to lowest

e.g.

```
<a href="link.html" title="5601">Link</a>
<a href="link.html" title="6001">Link</a>
<a href="link.html" title="7801">Link</a>
<a href="link.html" title="5618">Link</a>
<a href="link.html" title="4101">Link</a>
<a href="link.html" title="2001">Link</a>
```

to

```
<a href="link.html" title="7801">Link</a>
<a href="link.html" title="6001">Link</a> 
<a href="link.html" title="5618">Link</a>
<a href="link.html" title="5601">Link</a>
<a href="link.html" title="4101">Link</a>
<a href="link.html" title="2001">Link</a>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this: http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/sorting-elements-with-jquery/

Using this, you could do something along The Lines of

```
$("a").sortElements(function(a, b){
    return $(a).attr("title") < $(b).attr("title") ? 1 : -1;
});
```